# Netbeans project won't recognise classes from library

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm fiddling with this for a few hours now: I've got some Java classes, distributed into packets, of which I'd like to make a library, so I can use them in multiple projects. From those files I've made a JAR file which looks like this:

```
web.jar
|__web
   |__business
   |  |__Error.java
   |  |__business.user
   |     |__User.java
   |     |__UserLoginVerification.java
   |__data
   |  |__data.database
   |     |__Database.java
   |     |__DatabaseConnectionHandler.java
   |__controller
```

Now, NetBeans allows the option to create your own library and add JAR files to it, and so I did. I added `web.jar` to my library and it shows up in the `Libraries`-folder in the `Projects`-menu and I can open them, too.

The problem arises when I try to `import web.data.database.Database;`, NetBeans gives an error and says that the package doen not exist. I've tried multiple things:

- Including the JAR file directly to the `Libraries`-folder,
- Adding a folder containing the same files to the library,
- Adding the same folder directly to the `Libraries`-folder

But nothing seems to work. What am I'm doing wrong and how could I fix this, so I can access eg. `Database.java` from my normal projectfolder?

Comment: Is this is your actual Project Tree?

Comment: No, this is the tree of my jar file that I've included in my library.